# Ordenamiento de arrays según el orden de otro arrays

Tags: c, ordenamiento

Tengo que ordenar líneas de texto según un elemento en particular "CANTIDAD" de mayor a menor, y luego transmitirlo a un nuevo txt. Conseguí almacenar ese dato en particular de cada línea "CANTIDAD" en un arrays con el plan de ordenar las cantidades de mayor a menor pero el tema es que tengo que ordenar también la información que esta anteriormente. Alguna idea de como podría resolverlo?.

ESTE ES EL CODIGO::

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {
    char linea[LARGO],codigo[50],producto[50],unidadmedida[50],stockminimo[50],cantidad[50],saldocosto[50],cantidades[50];
    
    

char*token;
 
FILE*archivo= fopen("mercadepo.txt","r");
FILE*archivo2= fopen("nuevo.txt","w");

fgets(linea,LARGO,archivo);
linea[0]='\0';

fgets(linea,LARGO,archivo);

do{
    token = strtok(linea,";");
    strcpy(codigo,linea);
    
    token = strtok(NULL,";");
    strcpy(producto,token);
    
    token = strtok(NULL,";");
    strcpy(unidadmedida,token);
    
    token = strtok(NULL,";");
    strcpy(stockminimo,token);
    
    token = strtok(NULL,";");
    strcpy(cantidad,token);
    
    token = strtok(NULL,";");
    strcpy(saldocosto,token);
    
    if((strcmp(unidadmedida,"Unidad")) == 0){
    
        strcat(cantidades,cantidad);
        
        codigo[0]='\0';
        producto[0]='\0';
        unidadmedida[0]='\0';   
        stockminimo[0]='\0';
        cantidad[0]='\0';
        saldocosto[0]='\0';
        linea[0]='\0';
        fgets(linea,LARGO,archivo);

    }else{
        codigo[0]='\0';
        producto[0]='\0';
        unidadmedida[0]='\0';   
        stockminimo[0]='\0';
        cantidad[0]='\0';
        saldocosto[0]='\0';
        fgets(linea,LARGO,archivo);
    }
    
    
 }while(!feof(archivo));

}

return 0
```

Como ven con ese STRTOK corte la información que necesito de cada línea.
Espero se entienda mi inconveniente.